# Implementación de use para namespace dinámico y cumplimiento con los PSR 4/12

Tags: php, poo, namespace, refactoring

Estoy implementando un `autoloader` dado el siguiente escenario:

**Estructura:**

Existe una Aplicación X que mediante FTP genera una estructura de directorios y archivos php:
Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde:
`index.php`: seria el controlador.
`libs`: es el directorio en donde se conecta la aplicación X y crea la estructura.
`p_xxxx`: es el directorio para cada formulario, desde `0001` hasta el `9999`.
`process.php`: es el archivo `php` donde se desarrolla la lógica del formulario `p_xxx`.
`lista.php`: es el archivo `php` donde se desarrolla la vista html del formulario `p_xxx`.

Según la documentación, para un archivo de clase con esta estructura:
**process.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Prueba\Dinamico\p_0001;

class Process
{
    public function Ejemplo(){
        echo 'process: p_0001';
    }
}
```

mi index debería lucir así:

**index.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Prueba\Dinamico;

/**
 * En esta sección es donde se agrega el formulario:
 * p_0001
 * pero se supone que este valor se recibe desde una variable de sesión del usuario:
 * $_SESSION['currentForm']='p_0001';
 *
 * entonces la linea de código del use no logro implementarla de forma dinámico:
 * y que cumpla con el PSR-4 y 12
 *
 */

use Libs\p_0001\Lista;
spl_autoload_register(function ($clase) {
    $file = strtolower(str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $clase)).'.php';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        require_once $file;
    }else{
        echo 'no se pudo cargar la Librería para esta Gestión.';
        die;
    }
});

$EjemploClase = new Lista();
$EjemploClase->Ejemplo();
```

**El problema**

como pueden ver, `use Libs\p_0001\Lista;` es estático no se como lograr acceder por ejemplo a `p_0003` o al nodo necesitado, implementando `$_SESSION['currentForm']` que es donde se guarda el valor del formulario ejem: `p_0003`.

No se como mantener implementar esto y al mismo tiempo mantener el estándar PSR 4 y 12. ya que si uso o implemento Métodos Mágicos el IDE no reconoce lo programado al ser un valor que cambia en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta el momento he realizado investigaciones sobre este tema y php no brinda soporte pata la construcción de espacios de nombre en tiempo real:
Ejemplo:

```php
use $variable1.'/'.$variable2.'/'.$variable3.'/'.$variable4.'/' as ClassFoo;
```

no existe forma de que algo así funcione actualmente. entonces como solucionar esto; la única forma es mediante la creación de la instancia desde una variable:

```php
$formulario = 'P_0001'; //this value must be dynamic from $_POST
$class      = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Libs\\' . $formulario . '\\Proceso';
//$classInstance = (new ReflectionClass($class))->newInstance();
//$classInstance::getInstance()->Ejemplo();

$classInstance = new $class();
$classInstance->Ejemplo();
```

No se encontró ningún problema en la ejecución de este ultimo ejemplo.
El problema entonces en el ambiente de desarrollo es con las herramientas:

1- Sublime Text 3 y 4: la opción de ir a definición funciona correctamente en el método `Ejemplo()` basado en un full text search.
2- PHPStorm: no brinda soporte para ir a le definición o donde es implementado el método.

***Nota:*** agradezco a quienes dejen en los comentario pruebas con otros editores o IDE.